# Select distinct pair in mysql, and the sum of a third value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to achieve the following:
In a table with three values, for each distinct combination of values in two columns, I wan't to sum the values in the third column.

Eg.

The following table:

`mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+------+
| A    | B    | num  |
+------+------+------+
| e    | f    |   34 |
| e    | f    |   45 |
| g    | h    |   22 |
| a    | f    |   55 |
| d    | g    |   66 |
| e    | f    |   67 |
| a    | f    |   88 |
| e    | g    |   36 |
| d    | g    |   44 |
+------+------+------+`

I would like:

`+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
| e    | f    | 146
| g    | h    | 22
| a    | f    | 143
| d    | g    | 110
| e    | g    | 36
+------+------+`

I initially thought this would be a simple combination of DISTINCT and SUM(), but no - can't seem to make any progress. 
Combining it with a subquery also proved difficult.
Various similar, but not identical questions have been asked. But not quite the same, and the solutions did not work.

Can anyone help me with this seemingly simple question?

Comment: Does the result have to be in the order you have shown?

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by`.

```
select A,B, sum(num) from test group by A,B;
```

Comment: Simple as that!
Thank you Adder.

Answer (score 0):

Just go with:

```
select sum(num),col1,col2 from table group by col1,col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query --

```
SELECT A
    ,B
    ,Sum(Number) AS Total
FROM TableName
GROUP BY A, B
ORDER BY A, B;
```